# Merge sort program always works, but sometimes says abort trap at the end

Tags: c++, runtime-error, mergesort

I'm a beginner C++ programmer just starting to learn about algorithms/data structures and am following along with a book to write a merge sort program. After converting the book's int arrays to int vectors the sorting still always seems to work, but it will occasionally spit out an error at the very end. I can't seem to figure out why this only happens sometimes. This is what it says:

```
mergesort_sa(36921,0x7fff74240000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f879a500118: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

I googled "Abort trap: 6" and it said something about writing to memory I don't own. I looked through my program and I think the left and right bounds I passed are correct so I don't understand why it's saying this. Anyone know why this is or able to tell me why it's only happening occasionally and not on every run? Here's my full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void merge(vector<int> &numbers, vector<int> &temp_numbers, int left, int mid, int right);
int l = 0, r = 0, m = 0;

void merge_sort(vector<int> &numbers, vector<int> &temp_numbers, int left, int right){     
    int mid;    

    if (right > left) {
        mid = (left+right)/2;
        cout << "LEFT SORT" << endl;
        l++;
        merge_sort(numbers, temp_numbers, left, mid);   
        cout << "RIGHT SORT"  << endl;
        r++;
        merge_sort(numbers, temp_numbers, mid+1, right); 
        cout << "MERGE" << endl;
        m++;
        merge(numbers, temp_numbers, left, mid+1, right);   
    }
}

void merge(vector<int> &numbers, vector<int> &temp_numbers, int left, int mid, int right){
    int i, left_end, size, temp_pos;
    left_end = mid - 1;
    temp_pos = left;
    size = right-left + 1;

    while ((left <= left_end) && (mid <= right)) {
        if (numbers[left] <= numbers[mid]) {
            temp_numbers[temp_pos] = numbers[left];
            temp_pos++;
            left++;
        }   
        else {
            temp_numbers[temp_pos] = numbers[mid];
            temp_pos++;
            mid++;
        }
    }
    while (left <= left_end) {
        temp_numbers[temp_pos] = numbers[left];
        left++;
        temp_pos++;
    }
    while (mid <= right) {
        temp_numbers[temp_pos] = numbers[mid];
        mid++;
        temp_pos++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        numbers[right] = temp_numbers[right];
        right--;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    vector<int> numbers, temp_numbers;
    int x, n;

    // setup
    cout << "Enter numbers to sort separated by spaces. Press Ctrl+D when you are finished.\n\n";
    while(cin >> x) {
        numbers.push_back(x);
    }
    n = numbers.size();
    temp_numbers.resize(n);
    cout << "\nCount: " << n << endl << "Numbers to be sorted: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    cout << endl << endl << "Steps taken:\n";

    // sort
    merge_sort(numbers, temp_numbers, 0, n-1);

    // print
    cout << endl << "Sorted array: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    cout << endl << endl << "left sorts: " << l << "  right sorts: " << r << "  merges: " << m << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call a program that randomly crashes "working". | "Anyone know why this is or able to tell me why it's only happening occasionally and not on every run?" - Do you feed it the same input on every run? Only specific inputs? Can you drop the reading from stdin and reproduce the problem with that specific array of numbers?

Comment: What I meant was that it always outputs the correct answer before sometimes giving that error. I tried many different inputs and can't determine what pattern makes it error, although it will always either error or not error for the same input, that doesn't fluctuate.

Comment: OK, list few examples of those inputs in your question -- both kinds.

Comment: I suspect you're writing off the end of your vector and corrupting your heap. A tool like valgrind could help find the problem.

Comment: One (possible) problem is there are n-1, mid-1, right-left+1 etc and the result is then used for indexing without checking is the result is > 0 (if you'd be using size_t you wouldn't have to check btw) and < vector.size() so any of those could be out of bounds. Not sure if that is the key problem though.

Comment: I would say (especially for a beginner as a learning step), find the shortest sequence that reproduces this, then load up a debugger and step through your code observing the indexes. Valgrind would certainly help, although it might be a little overwhelming at this level of experience.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've used gdb briefly before in class, but don't have it on my mac and the installation seems a bit complicated. I guess I need to take the time to learn the lldb one my mac came with.

Comment: @Jake -- If you're using `vector` the one thing you could have done to solve your own problem is to use `vector::at()` instead of `[ ]` to access the vector elements.  The reason is that using `at()` would have thrown an `out_of_range` exception as soon as you went out of bounds of your vector, with giving the reasons for the exception (instead of random crashes).  Once you get that straightened out using `at()`, then you change back to using `[ ]`.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about the at() function

Comment: @Jake -- See your program failing when using `at()` [here](http://ideone.com/myevyO).  Now see your program "working" when using `[ ]`.[here](http://ideone.com/aHZvEQ).  See that -- using `[ ]` gave you the false sense that your program was working when it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copy your merge results from the temp space back to the main space, you sometimes access outside the bounds of your vectors.  Observe:

> ```
> size = right-left + 1;
> ```

Because the `right` and `left` indices are inclusive, `size` therefore holds the number of elements in the subarray being merged.  But then you do this:

> ```
> for (i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
>     numbers[right] = temp_numbers[right];
>     right--;
> }
> ```

That performs `size + 1` iterations, whereas you only want to copy `size` elements.  When `left` is 0, that accesses outside (below) the bounds of the vectors, at index -1.

Even if that did not produce memory errors, it is sheer luck that it does not corrupt your data.  This appears to arise from the fact that you recurse for the left half of each partition first, so that whenever you have an overrun of this type that is actually in-bounds for the overall vector, the value already present in the temp space is one arising from a previous merge, thus copying it to the corresponding position in the main space has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
    numbers[right] = temp_numbers[right];
    right--;
}
```

The problem is in the above code segment.It should run till `size-1`

Comment: Yes, though I'd characterize the correct code as running while `i` is strictly less than `size` (`i < size`).  That's equivalent to what you said, but a little cleaner and clearer.